# Can I configure gulp-jasmine to run tests in a browser?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Can I configure gulp-jasmine to run tests in a browser, or do I need to use something like gulp-jasmine-phantom?

Answer (score 1):

`gulp-jasmine` would run your tests with [`jasmine` command-line-interface](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/node.html).

If you want browser-based tests, look into [`karma` test runner](http://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html).